# R programing read multiple .CSV files

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to import and read multiple csv files and figure out the mean. when I test with the id being `1:10` everything works fine. However, as soon as I change the `1` to a different number (like `2`) I get the following error

```
--Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message:
--In file(file, "rt") :
--  cannot open file 'specdata/002.csv': No such file or directory
```

I believe i am not properly defining the list but I am not sure. My code is below, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory=getwd(), pollutant, id = 1:132){

  filename<-c()

  for (i in id){
    filename1<-id[i]
    filename2<-sprintf('%03d.csv', filename1)
  filepath<-file.path(directory,filename2)
  files<-read.csv(filepath,header=TRUE)
  filename<-c(filename,files[[pollutant]])
  }
  pollutantmean<-mean(filename, na.rm=TRUE)
  pollutantmean


}
```

My system is MAC os10.10.1 MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012)

Comment: Search for '[r] pollutantmean'

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file path is correct. Look at my code and see if it works for you. Note that I used list.files in order to look for those CSV before running the for loop.

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory=getwd(), pollutant, id = 1:132){

  #List of your CSV files in directory
  filenames <- list.files(path = directory, pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)

  #If you want to create the file names by yourself, use the following line instead
  #filenames <- paste(id,".csv",sep="")

  #We are going to store the data here
  pollutant_data <- NULL

  #Now read your files from the filenames vector
  for (f in filenames){
    fdata <- read.csv(f, header=TRUE)
    pollutant_data <- c(pollutant_data,fdata$pollutant)
  }

  poll_mean <- mean(pollutant_data, na.rm=TRUE) 

  return(poll_mean)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Emer, that works but I figured out how to get it to work with sprintf.

I had`filename2<-sprintf('%03d.csv', filename1)` I should have had `filename2<-sprintf('%03d.csv', i)`

That made it work. Thanks